# If and For in Play Framework's email template

Tags: email, playframework, template-engine

I am writing a email notification part of a project using Play Framework.I don't know how to use if and for loop in the email template. All I can find are using ${var} to show specific variables in the email.

Comment: Write more details: especially what version of Play are you using and what did you try, show us something

Comment: I am using Play 1.4.0, I find that Play 1.x use the same template engine as of in html, so problem is solved

Answer (score 1):

The Mailer class uses the same template engine as of in HTML. So we can just use the syntax of html to write a mail template.